# WPF showing Table using Grid in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, view

I am trying to show a Table using Grid in XAML in WPF.

My [XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/xaml) code in my [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/) app is like this-

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" Background="Yellow">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Valid From" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValidFrom}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Valid To" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValidTo}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="SigningTime" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SigningTime}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

What I am getting like this-

[image]

I like to have a clean table, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have two rows in the grid but three rows of data.

You should add another rowdefinition:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

If you set grid.row to 2, the rows are zero based so this looks for a third row.

When there are less rows ( or columns ) than the attached property interpretation defaults to the last valid one and hence puts two sets of data into your second row with your current markup.